# My function() won't run?

Tags: javascript

With this function I am trying to show a lightbulb that switches on and off once the user clicks it.

```
(function () {
    var FavData, ImageData, create_zip, fav, favData;

    window.imageData = [];

    saveButton = document.createElement("save_button");
    saveButton.innerHTML = "save_button";
    saveButton.onclick = function () {
        var image = document.getElementById('save_button');
        if (image.src.match("http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif")) {
            image.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif";
        } else {
            image.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif";
        }
    };
}).call(this);
```

And my html:

```
<button id="save_button"><img src="image" width="100" height="180"></button>
```

with the id "save_button".

Comment: `document.createElement` should create an element which is a `valid` and  `saveButton = document.createElement("save_button");`. You should either try creating `div`, `span`, `input` etc which are valid `html` elements

Comment: You are only creating the button element above. You need to add it to the page/DOM, before it can be clicked.

Comment: Your code runs just fine.

Comment: Also `<save_button>` isn't a valid tagName.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issue with your code. You are not creating element using a tag. After that you are not appending it to the body. And on the button click you have to take the image id to get the source and not the button.

Here is the fiddle of a working functionality.

http://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/9vyauhvf/

```
(function () {
    var FavData, ImageData, create_zip, fav, favData;

    window.imageData = [];

    saveButton = document.createElement("button");
    saveButton.id = "save_button"
    img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif";
    img.id = "save-btn-img";
    saveButton.appendChild(img);
    document.body.appendChild(saveButton);
    saveButton.onclick = function () {
        var image = document.getElementById('save-btn-img');
        if (image.src.match("http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif")) {
            image.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif";
        } else {
            image.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif";
        }
    };
}).call(this);
```

Comment: how did you write this code? did you major in computer science?

Comment: @GeorgeSusan it will come with experience. Keep using it and keep watching videos on youtube. That can help you.